# Connection of Titan graph DB to Gephi through Gremlin console

Tags: titan, gremlin, gephi

I am trying to connect to gephi(0.9.1) through gremlin console. I have a graph in my titan database. I also have the streaming server enabled in my gephi. And through gremlin i executed the following commands:

1. :plugin use tinkerpop.gephi
2. g = TinkerFactory.createModern()
3. :remote connect tinkerpop.gephi

All these worked fine.But when i ran the last command:

```
                      :> g
```

I got the following error:

```
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
16:07:16.783 [main] DEBUG groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder - POST http://localhost:8080/workspace0?format=JSON&operation=updateGraph
16:07:16.801 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.BasicClientConnectionManager - Get connection for route {}->http://localhost:8080
16:07:16.809 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultClientConnectionOperator - Connecting to localhost:8080
16:07:16.817 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: default
16:07:16.822 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
16:07:16.826 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.p.RequestTargetAuthentication - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED 
16:07:16.831 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.p.RequestProxyAuthentication - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
16:07:16.836 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Attempt 1 to execute request
16:07:16.840 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Sending request: POST /workspace0?format=JSON&operation=updateGraph HTTP/1.1
16:07:16.850 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "POST /workspace0?format=JSON&operation=updateGraph HTTP/1.1[\r][\n ]"
16:07:16.862 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
16:07:16.868 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Content-Length: 23[\r][\n]"
16:07:16.873 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
16:07:16.879 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Host: localhost:8080[\r][\n]"
16:07:16.885 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
16:07:16.890 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "[\r][\n]"
16:07:16.895 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> POST /workspace0?format=JSON&operation=updateGraph HTTP/1.1
16:07:16.900 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Accept: */*
16:07:16.905 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Content-Length: 23
16:07:16.910 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Content-Type: application/json
16:07:16.915 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Host: localhost:8080
16:07:16.920 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
16:07:16.925 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  >> "{"dn":{"filter":"ALL"}}"
16:07:16.935 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found[\r][\n]"
16:07:16.940 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store[\r][\n]"
16:07:16.945 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1[\r][\n]"
16:07:16.951 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Content-Length: 1277[\r][\n]"
16:07:16.956 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "Server: Jetty(8.1.17.v20150415)[\r][\n]"
16:07:16.961 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "[\r][\n]"
16:07:16.966 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
16:07:16.971 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
16:07:16.978 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
16:07:16.984 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1 
16:07:16.991 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Content-Length: 1277
16:07:16.996 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - << Server: Jetty(8.1.17.v20150415)
16:07:17.002 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
16:07:17.010 [main] DEBUG groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder - Response code: 404; found handler: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime. MethodClosure@2c768ada
16:07:17.020 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "<html>[\n]"
16:07:17.024 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "<head>[\n]"
16:07:17.029 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>[\n]"
16:07:17.039 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>[\n]"
16:07:17.043 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "</head>[\n]"
16:07:17.048 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "<body>[\n]"
16:07:17.052 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "<h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>[\n]"
16:07:17.057 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "<p>Problem accessing /workspace0. Reason:[\n]"
16:07:17.062 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>[\n]"
16:07:17.068 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>[\n]"
16:07:17.074 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                           [\n]"
16:07:17.079 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                               [\n]"
 16:07:17.083 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.088 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.093 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.098 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.103 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.107 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.111 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.116 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.121 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.125 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.130 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.136 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.141 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.146 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.151 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.156 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.160 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.165 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "                                                [\n]"
 16:07:17.170 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "</body>[\n]"
 16:07:17.174 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire -  << "</html>[\n]"
 16:07:17.178 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.BasicClientConnectionManager - Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@c1fca2a
 16:07:17.188 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.BasicClientConnectionManager - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely Not Found
 Display stack trace? [yN]
```

And also often i get:

```
 15:38:20.276 [Finalizer] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Connection 0.0.0.0:60710<->127.0.0.1:8080 closed
```

I have checked for the opened ports, and i also found that 8080 port is opened.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the Gephi Plugin was only recently made compliant with Gephi 0.9.x as of TinkerPop 3.2.1-SNAPSHOT [a few days ago](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/bwHs7ldex-Y). As you are using Titan 1.0, I would guess that you have an older version. I would recommend going back to Gephi 0.8.x beta if you want everything to work seamlessly.

All that said, you might yet be able to get it to work.  The default workspace that Gephi provides is no longer "workspace0" - it is now indexed starting at "1". You can change the workspace used by the Gremlin remote by doing:

```
:remote config workspace workspace1
```

That should allow the data to be sent to Gephi and it should show in the "laboratory" pane. You may yet have problems with the visualization. I found that while fixing this problem that not auto-setting the "size", "x" and "y" properties to "sensible" things seemed to prevent the visualization pane from displaying the vertices and edges. I think that you would need to add those properties to any graph you wanted to push across to Gephi. The patch I did set the size to "10" and the x/y were set to a random float - setting them all to to zero/zero (i.e. the same positions) did not work.

All of the above workaround instructions are mostly for informational purposes.  That's probably a lot of extra work that you don't need to do when downloading Gephi 0.8.x is a pretty easy course of action.