# Export graph from remote titan to gephi in local

Tags: titan, gremlin, gephi

I have setup titan-1.0.0 in linux server and have gephi in local windows machine. I am trying to connect gephi through gremlin. I have given the command,

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.gephi
:remote config host 182.76.249.161
```

which is my local machine ip. And also i have submitted the graph

```
:> g
```

I dint get any error after submitting it. But i dont get the graph in my gephi. Please help me out

This is what i got in my linux in html format. I have attached the picture which i got in when i gave the url http://182.76.249.161:8080/ in my local machine[image]

Comment: what version of gephi are you using?

Comment: I'm using 0.9.1 gephi version

Comment: Why is this problem different than what you succeeded in doing before? http://stackoverflow.com/a/37299573/1831717 - and why are you changing the host to that IP address if your connecting to gephi locally (shouldn't you just connect to gephi on local host)?

Comment: That i had done, when i was using same version of titan and gephi locally. But, in this case, titan is in the linux server and gephi is in my local. So, in gremlin i have changed the ip to my local machine ip where my gephi is present.

Comment: The gephi runs with url "localhost:8080/workspace1"; but not with "182.76.249.161:8080/workspace1"[Error 404:Not Found], when i ran this on my local machine. The graph from titan is not sent to "182.76.249.161:8080/workspace1", which is local machine ip. I have no clue how else to send it to my local machine. And gephi takes only "localhost" :/ ... How do i get the graph in gephi?

Comment: so you are running the gremlin console (bin/gremlin.sh) on the linux server and trying to visualize to gephi on another machine? is that your configuration or something else?

Comment: Yes!! Exactly... Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The streaming plugin uses Jetty for its internal server. I don't see where [the code](https://github.com/panisson/gephi-plugins/blob/a80c3ea1c3996c168e449e6cca0856d6ad420037/modules/StreamingServer/src/main/java/org/gephi/streaming/server/impl/jetty/StreamingServerImpl.java#L164) specifically sets the host, so according to [Jetty documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/quickstart-config-what.html) that should mean that Jetty/Gephi are listening on all interfaces:

> You can configure a host either as a host name or IP address to
>   identify a specific network interface on which to listen. If not set,
>   or set to the value of 0.0.0.0, the connector listens on all local
>   interfaces.

I suggest you ensure that the port (8080 in your case it seems) you are connecting with to Gephi is open. You can do that with a simple cURL command from your Linux instance:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously, you should change "localhost" to match your IP address. If that command fails to return the 404, then Gephi's Jetty server is not available externally and I suspect that you need to look into the network configuration of your system.

Comment: I have attached the pic which i got in my Local machine. I got the same in HTML format in my linux server

Comment: You should be getting a 404 from jetty - Doesn't your picture/description indicate that you aren't connecting to Jetty and therefore have a network problem to solve?

Comment: i get "This site cannot be reached" when i give url "http://170.251.154.205:8080/workspace1" and i get 404 error when i give url "http://localhost:8080/workspace1" in my local windows machine. I haven't changed any configuration

Comment: So a 404 on your local machine means you can connect from there. "This site cannot be reached" doesn't sound like a 404 to me and sounds indicative of a network problem. If you have already validated that the port is open and that a firewall (likely windows firewall - just turn it off if you can) isn't blocking the outside traffic, then i'm not sure what else I can advise you to do, but this definitely sounds like a network problem to me.

Comment: the url keeps loading... I am not sure if the data from gremlin is passed to that url.. How do i find that?

Comment: what do you mean the "url keeps loading"?

Comment: Nothing is displayed in that page [URL:http://10.231.101.162:8080/workspace1].. But keeps loading

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see anything. It's not a web site. That is a REST API endpoint. Did you check your ports/firewall as I suggested? What does curl return when you issue the command I provided in my answer?

Comment: The problem is i dont see anything in my gephi. When i enable the master server it shows me nothing

Comment: You didn't answer my two questions or respond in any way to my answer's assertion that this is a network problem, so I guess you think it is something else. Perhaps this just isn't going to work for you.